# Heroku-Client module .delete to restart dyno not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, request, dyno

I have a memory leak and would like to apply a temporary patch while I debug it. I want to restart the dyno whenever a specific request from a client comes in. I'm assuming appName below is just this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDpdh.png

Here is the constant/module declaration:

```
const requestModule = require('request');
var token = process.env.HEROKU_API_TOKEN;
var appName = 'app-name';
```

I'd like to restart the dyno inside a POST request I've made using this code:

```
requestModule.delete(
  {
    url: 'https://api.heroku.com/apps/' + appName + '/dynos/',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  },
  function(error, response, body) {
    // Do stuff
    console.log("ran the restart")
  }
);
```

'ran the restart' prints to the Heroku logs but the dyno doesn't seem to actually restart (I assumed I would see it restarting in the logs as well, and there's no output). I need to do this to temporarily fix a memory leak.